# Searching for records in a database with SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

I've created a database of my inbox and currently working on some search functionality.

The database looks something like this:

```
ID | candidate.id (foreign key) | email_id | thread_id | ... | epoch _time
```

I'm trying to create a search that will look at all of the rows that share the same `candidate.id` and if none of them have an `epoch_time` less than X

So for example:

```
1 | 1 | email123 | thread123 | 1416002109.0
2 | 1 | email456 | thread123 | 1415742971.0
3 | 1 | email789 | thread123 | 1415224564.0
```

if `X` is 1416000000.0 it won't return any (be because the first record is greater than `X`).

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure to how to go about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand you want to group by candicate.id and check if any epoch time less then x time:

```
q = session.query(inbox).group_by(candicate.id).having(epoch_time<X)
```